# How does PS Vita work with PS1/PSP games?

Tags: backwards-compatibility, ps-vita

What do PS1 and/or PSP games look like on the PS Vita? Do they fill the screen?

Also since the PSP has only one analog stick, for PSP games like Monster Hunter where they used the PSPs face buttons as a analog stick replacement - if I play them on the Vita, can I use the second analog stick? Or do I have to use the face buttons?

Will the games play the same as they did on the older system? Or will there be changes to conform to the new system?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

PSP games can be upscaled and bilinearly filtered to the Vita's full resolution of 960x544. Also, the colorspace can be changed to brighter colors to take better advantage of the Vita's OLED screen.

The second analog stick is configurable in PSP games to emulate any of the following:

- The left analog stick.
- The face buttons.
- The D-pad.
- The L and R buttons.

Comment: ohh!!! nice! good deal! thanks for the reply........now i have to figure out what games imma get lol.

Comment: Yep. PSP Monster Hunter but without "the claw" :-)

Comment: Note that 960x544 is exactly 2x the PSP screen resolution, and the bilinear filtering is optional - you can choose pixel doubling instead and still use the whole screen, which looks much better in some games.